# jQuery clickable styled dropdown list, click to close

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu with `ul`s and `li`s so I can apply styles.

The current problem I have is that I want to be able to click on the `Select an option` box to close the menu along with anywhere else on the page.

In essence I want it to perform like a normal `select` box, but one that can be styled.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="section">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>
                <div class="value">
                    <span class="text">Select an Option</span>
                </div>

                <ul class="list">
                    <li>Option 1</li>
                    <li>Option 2</li>
                    <li>Option 3</li>
                    <li>Option 4</li>
                    <li>Option 5</li> 
                    <li>Option 6</li> 
                    <li>Option 7</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#section .container .value {
    padding: 0;
}

#section .container span {
    color: #666;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
}

#section .container .text {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#section .list li {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#section .list li:hover,
#section .list li:focus,
#section .list li:active {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

#section .container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 260px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

#section .container ul {
    position: relative;
}

#section .container ul li {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#section .container li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    display: none;
    outline: 1px solid #bebebe;
}

#section .container ul .value {
    position: relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.container').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.list').show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on('click', function() {
    if ($('.list').is(':visible')) {
        $('.list', this).hide();
    }
});
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/xareyo/t2Ltm/4/

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.container .list li').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().prev().find('.text').text($(this).text());
});
$(document).on('click', function () {
    if ($('.list').is(':visible')) {
        $('.list', this).hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/77SgW/)

Comment: He wants to have a `select` behaviour, so, the selected option must appears in the span. (I'm not the downvotter)

Comment: Hi, this is perfect. I don't need that TCHdvlp, just the click to close part.

Comment: @Xareyo it switches the display property... ie if visible then hide, if not display so when you select a value the dropdown list is visible to it hides it

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as per my understanding your problem

```
$('.container').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($('.list').is(':visible')) {
        $('.list', this).hide();
    }
    else{
      $('.list').show();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t2Ltm/6/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I would like to be able to click on elsewhere on the page to close it.